# Error finding preseed file when booting the UbuntuServer installer via iPXE through HTTP

Tags: networking, system-installation, pxe, filename

I know the typical settings to run a PXE server is the combination DHCP+TFTP+HTTP/FTP/NFS... servers, but my setting must be only DHCP+HTTP, so my dhcpd.conf has these lines:

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.10;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    ...
    filename "http://192.168.1.1/pxelinux.0";
}
```

I use iPXE (http://www.ipxe.org) -which can get pxelinux.0 from a HTTP server- to boot my clients. They see a pxelinux menu with an option to run Ubuntu installer. Its "APPEND" line is like this:

```
APPEND url=http://192.168.1.1/mountpointisoubuntu/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed
```

Everythings seems going well during installation until I get a error message:

```
The installer failed to process preconfiguration file from http://192.168.1.1/pxelinux.0
```

I've read in [Chapter B.2.5 of the Debian Installation Guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs02.html.en) that if dhcpd.conf there is a HTTP url, the installer assumes it is the url of a preseed file.

I thought that appending the "url" preseed parameter this behaviour would be overriden, but it is not! What can I do to tell the installer to forget using the url from dhcpd.conf as a preseed file's url?

Comment: Ouch!  Using a protocol for a netboot file to retrieve a preseed file is abnormal! -- "Normally this is a file to netboot, but if it appears to be an URL then installation media that support network preseeding will download the file from the URL and use it as a preconfiguration file." (debian install guide)

Comment: [Link](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/mipsel/apbs02.html.en#preseed-dhcp) to Debian guide for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two options:

1. Change the `APPEND` line so that it uses static IP settings instead of going out looking for DHCP. This way it should never see the DHCP `filename`.
2. Change your DHCP server configuration so that it serves the `filename` only to requests not from a Debian installer. The example given in the Installation guide can be easily adapted:

   ```
   # your normal settings
   if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 3) != "d-i" {
       filename "http://192.168.1.1/pxelinux.0";
   }
   ```

Comment: Oooh, yes!!! It works!! Thanks a lot. I've added a else clause to go to filename "http://192.168.1.1/isoUbuntu/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed" and the problem has been solved. Thanks, thanks, thanks!!!